# Windows 2016 Server License on a VMWare VM

Tags: vmware, license, windows-server

What I am needing to know is the following.

I have a server with multiple cores, each VM (VMware Machine) is assigned one core per machine. (It is Not a strong machine, that will come later on in the year.

I have two questions:

1. How does the Windows 2016 Server License work, on a VM, with a single core?
2. If I get a license for each of the VM's that are on the system, and if for some reason, I have to reinstall one or more of the VM's. How would that affect the License that is attached to the existing VM? What if I have to purchase another license for each re-install or will the License cross over to the newly installed VM as long as the VM Machine name is the same?

UPDATE----
You have to purchase a 16-core license pack or more. Nothing less.
Standard = $882.00 US for a 2 proc, 16 core
Datacenter = $6,155.00 US for a 2 proc, 16 core

If you have a system like what I have at the current time, which is
2 proc, 8 core (4 cores for proc)
Then you have to get the 16 core license pack.

However, I can not find rather this one pack, will install across ALL VM's or not? If it will install across all the VM's then that will be great.

Anymore incite on this, would be greatly appreciated.

EE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard license allows you to run 2 instances of Windows Server in a VM OSE - be it Hyper-V or VMWare. Windows Server licneses only physical host, not operating system environment. If you intend to license more than 2 VMs on a host, you need to buy Standard version * times (so for 6 VMs, 3* Standard 16-core license pack). For Datacenter, you are entitled to unlimited VM installations of Windows Server Datacenter (it has some additional features). 
Hope this helps!
Alex Pawlak

Comment: Thanks.
I forgot all about posting this question here.
I had found this information out a while back as well.
It is insane how much it cost for these licenses.